# create table of 2dim array in javascript/knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-templates

i have an 2dim array in javascript, like this

```
        for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
                tab[i][j] = ko.observable(tab[i][j]);
            }
            tab[i] = ko.observableArray(tab[i]);
        }
        this.TabValues = ko.observableArray(tab);
```

Now i want to create a table with no fixed columns and rows.

```
<script type="text/html" id="table">     
        <table data-bind="template: {name: 'rows', foreach: TabValues}">

        </table>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="rows">
    <tr data-bind="template: {name: 'columns', foreach: TabValues()[i]}">
    </tr>
</script>
```

To achieve this, i created a table template and within it a rows template. But now i dont know how to create a template for the colums, because in the foreach statement i would need an index. but i have got none. how can i do that.

Maybe you have another approach how to fix this. My aim is to create an editable table with no fixed rows/columns size.

i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your inner template, you can use `$data` to refer to the current data.  This will be an array of cells, so you can do `"template: {name: 'columns', foreach: $data }"`.

Here is a really basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KcghG/